# Getting ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'old_production' database is not configured when trying to deploy rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, capistrano3

I have a new rails 4.2 app.

In order to perform a migration from an old database to the new one, I added a rake task that defines some OldXX classes connecting to the old database, converts data and saves it to new database. **The task works from localhost in development** against old database on the server.

**convert.rake**

```
class OldActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "old_#{Rails.env}".to_sym
end

class OldUser < OldActiveRecord
  ...
end

...
```

**database.yml** which is **not** present in / linked to `shared` on production.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5

production:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
  username: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>"
  password: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"

old_production: &old_prod
  <<: *default
  host: my.old.dbhost
  database: "<%= ENV['OLD_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
  username: "<%= ENV['OLD_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>"
  password: "<%= ENV['OLD_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"

old_development:
  <<: *old_prod

old_test:
  <<: *old_prod
```

and the env vars are set up in **.env** which **is** in `shared` on production.

### Problem

When I deploy with `capistrano` I'm getting the error

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as me@my.old.dbhost: rake exit status: 1
rake stderr: rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'old_production' database is not configured. Available: []

/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/www.domain.org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:250:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/www.domain.org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/www.domain.org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/www.domain.org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
```

/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/www.domain.org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/

right after `do bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Adding a `p Rails.configuration.database_configuration` before `establish_connection` shows that all fields for `old_production` are set accordingly, including `adapter`. Connection from new host to old host for mysql is also possible, tested with the same credentials on command line.

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

### Update

When I add a `p configurations` in `/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/www.domain.org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:245` at the top of `#resolve_symbol_connection` it says

```
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = Rails.application.config.database_configuration
```

at the top of `convert.rake` in order to make it work, but actually I still don't know why this needs to be done.